# How to call two fadeslideshow plugin in the jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a home page having fadeslideshow with 5 slides. The plugin used for slideshow is http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fadeslideshow.

In the home page i also have Menu bar with menu items in it. When user clicks the menu item the slideshow content should be removed and one more slideshow should be added with menu items content. One more problem is, I need autoslideshow true for home page, but false for menu items slideshow. So i need to call slideshow.js file twice in the jquery. I tried with this but its not working.

The jquery code where i am calling the plugin. This is used for home page.

```
slide=jQuery('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow(
{width:936, height:476, autoplay:true});
```

When user clicks menu item the '#slideshow' content will be removed and menu items div will be loaded.

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu li a').click( function(event) {
    $('#slideshowWrapper1').empty().load('test.html');
    slide=jQuery('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow(
    { width:936, height:476, autoplay:false});

    var newTopicContent = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(newTopicContent);


   });
```

The code for home page with 5 slideshow

```
<div id="slideshowWrapper1">
            <div id="slideshow" class="slides">
                <div class="5">
                    <div class="txtCenter" > <p> This is 5th slide</p></div>    
                </div>              
                <div class="4">
                    <div class="txtCenter" >
                <img src="images/new/home4.png" alt="" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="3">
                    <div class="txtCenter" ><p>This is third slide</p></div>                    
                </div>
                <div class="2">

                    <div style="text-align: center;margin-top: 2%;"><img src="images/new/some.png" alt="" /></div>
                    <br style="clear:both;"/>
                </div>
                <div class="1">
                    <div><img src="images/new/recreate.png" alt="" /></div>
                    <br style="clear:both;"/>
                </div>  

            </div>          
        </div>
```

The test.html page has different contents for menu items. Here in my code the first slideshow is working very fine. But after clicking the menu item slideshow is not working. All slide contents coming in the same page.
I need help. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please help me  @Cerlin Boss

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to remove the first slideshow to replace with a new slideshow returned via test.html ?

I think you must wait for test.html to be load using `load(url, callback)`
see http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu li a').click( function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#slideshowWrapper1').empty().load('test.html', function() {
        slide=jQuery('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow(
        { width:936, height:476, autoplay:false});

        var newTopicContent = id;
        alert(newTopicContent);
    });
});
```